# Display HTML code from $_POST variable

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to send html code using post by the following JavaScript code:

```
var htmlTable= $('#granting_result').html();
alert(htmlTable);
$('<form action="tbl_create.php" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="data" value='+htmlTable+' ></form>').submit();
```

The receiving page `tbl_create.php` has the following php code:

```
<?php

echo $_POST['data'];

?>
```

The problem is that this page is shown as a blank page and nothing displayed, although the output of  `alert(htmlTable);` is as following:
[image]

Comment: This sounds like a job for Ajax, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the form elements themselves and pass the html string as value property of the input instead of concatenating as attribute.

Then insert into dom and submit

```
var $input = $('<input>',{type:'hidden', name:'data'}).val(htmlTable);
var $form = $('<form>',{method:'post', action:'tbl_create.php'});
$form.append($input).appendTo('body').submit();
```

Answer (score 2):

You're building a string. You're inserting HTML into that string. That means the html you build looks like

```
<form><input ... value=<html><body>....
```

There's no quotes on your `value`, so the FIRST space in that blob of html you're inserting TERMINATES that attribute, leaving the rest of the html as illegal/unknown attributes.

If you want to embed HTML inside an attribute, you have to html-encode it

```
foo = '<form><input ....value="' + encodeHTML(var_with_html) + '">....';
```

producing

```
<form><input ... value="&lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt; ... &quot; etc..." ...
```

for the encoding function: [HTML-encoding lost when attribute read from input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use load javascript method instead of `$('#granting_result').html();`